# Error al tratar de insertar datos ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, ms-access

Tengo un `GridView` con varios `Textboxs` en el `Footer`, esto para tratar de insertar, pero al momento de darle clic al botón, este falla y me dice que está incorrecto el *statement*.

Estoy usando como prueba de BD una en access

mi codigo es el siguiente ya que lo acabado de actualizar, no inserta pero tampoco muestra error de sintaxis ni nada por el estilo

```
protected void dataGridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button bt = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)bt.Parent.Parent;

            TextBox Txt_who = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("Txt_who");
            int Txt_pay_roll = Convert.ToInt32(grdRow.Cells[1].FindControl("Txt_pay_roll"));
            TextBox Txt_name = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[2].FindControl("Txt_name");
            TextBox Txt_ou = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[3].FindControl("Txt_ou");
            int Txt_pool = Convert.ToInt32(grdRow.Cells[4].FindControl("Txt_pool"));
            int Txt_team = Convert.ToInt32(grdRow.Cells[5].FindControl("Txt_team"));
            int Txt_rol = Convert.ToInt32(grdRow.Cells[6].FindControl("Txt_rol"));

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *  FROM users"))
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();

                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (who, payroll_number, ou, pool, team, rol_id) VALUES (@WHO, @PAYROLL_NUMBER, @NAME, @OU, @POOL @TEAM, @ROL_ID)";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WHO", Txt_who.Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAYROLL_NAME", Txt_who.Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OU", Txt_who.Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POOL", Txt_who.Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEAM", Txt_who.Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROL_ID", Txt_who.Text.Trim());
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

y  el error que me marca es el siguiente

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: ¿Nos puedes compartir el error exacto que te tira y la línea donde se genera la falla? Y de ser posible, de igual forma el *Stack Trace* de la excepción.

Comment: claro, ya edite la publicacion

Comment: Como recomendación, no pongas imágenes, es preferible poner el texto de la excepción así como el *stack trace* completos pero como texto.

Comment: En esta línea `catch (Exception)` coloca así: `catch (Exception ex) { MesasgeBox.Show(ex.Message); }`. Además, en el insert, si estás enviando strings, te hacen falta las comillas sencillas para encerrar los valores.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave intente poner el mensaje en el catch pero me marca que  `The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context` y le intent agregar el using `system.forms` pero me dice que no `existe en el namespace system`

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos, error mío, pensé que estabas programando en windows-forms. Entonces, en vez de usar MessageBox, guarda el error en un string. ¿tu sabes de puntos de interrupción?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Hablas sobre los `BreakPoints`? si hablas de eso, de hecho tengo varios y al momento de dar clic al boton, ni siquiera entran

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos, si, hablo de los breakpoints. Mirando mas tu código, veo que no estás guardando "solo estás abriendo la conexión". ¿Ya viste el tutorial que indicó cport93 [en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68234/error-al-tratar-de-insertar-datos-asp-net?noredirect=1#comment124978_68257)?

Comment: De hecho, @MauricioAriasOlave ya cambie mi codigo, de igual manera dejame actualizarlo aqui para que lo observen

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes proporcionar mayor información de laguno de los textbox de tu footer, ya que a simple vista no estas enviandole ningún parámetro a tus variables declaradas dentro del query.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WHO", valuedeltxt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAYROLL_NUMBER", valuedeltxt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OU", valuedeltxt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POOL", valuedeltxt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEAM", valuedeltxt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROL_ID", valuedeltxt);
```

Comment: el boton no lo tengo en el footer, esta por aparte del GridView

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, me refería a los textbox, ¿Estas guardando los values de los txt?, si es así tienes que insertarlos en el command.

Comment: hmm no, no estoy guardando los values de los txt... como tendria que hacer eso?

Comment: Si estás usando un gridview, puedes seleccionar 'editar los campos', luego en la ventana que te abre, seleccionas el campo del txt, presionas convertir a template, y te habilitará para que puedas ver el TXT individual. y así ya en asp puedes poner por ejemplo 
var_who varchar;
var_who = TextBox1.value;

Comment: Ya lo hice como me dijiste pero no me aparece la opcion

Comment: Podes revisar este tutorial: [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos cosas por corregir:

- No es necesario que hagas un `SELECT` a todos los usuarios cuando haces uso del contexto `using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *  FROM users"))`.
- De debe agregar una validación `if(!Page.IsPostBack){ ... }` en evento `dataGridView1_SelectedIndexChanged`.

De tal forma que el código debe quedar:

```
protected void dataGridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {   
        Button bt = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)bt.Parent.Parent;

        TextBox Txt_who = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("Txt_who");
        TextBox Txt_pay_roll = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[1].FindControl("Txt_pay_roll");
        TextBox Txt_name = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[2].FindControl("Txt_name");
        TextBox Txt_ou = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[3].FindControl("Txt_ou");
        TextBox Txt_pool = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[4].FindControl("Txt_pool");
        TextBox Txt_team = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[5].FindControl("Txt_team");
        TextBox Txt_rol = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[6].FindControl("Txt_rol");

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WHO", Txt_who.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAYROLL_NUMBER", Txt_pay_roll.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Txt_name.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OU", Txt_ou.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POOL", Txt_pool.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEAM", Txt_team.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROL_ID", Txt_rol.Text);

                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (who, payroll_number, ou, pool, team, rol_id) VALUES (@WHO, @PAYROLL_NUMBER, @NAME, @OU, @POOL @TEAM, @ROL_ID)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        BindGrid_With_Data();
    }
}
```

No conozco los tipos de dato pero es posible que requieras de una conversión, por ejemplo, para el campo `ROL_ID`, ya que por ser un `ID` podría suponer que es un `INT`:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROL_ID", Convert.ToInt32(Txt_rol.Text));
```

Comment: Me ayudo a solucionar el erro que mandaba pero sigue sin inserter los datos en la BD de access, ya he intentado de todas maneras y no lo consigo

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos ¿Cuál es el error que te manda?

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos sin los errores exactos que te manda el compilador es difícil adivinar lo que se tiene que solucionar

Comment: No marca ningún error solo disquete hace él commit del query pero no hace nada, no inserta nada en access